# I want to create a "picture section" like Facebook

Tags: html, css, web

I am designing a website where users will be making post which has a section for text and a section for pictures (if there are any). I want to design the section for the pictures like the way Facebook handle it. Which means, when the user post a picture or more, they will be resized and some of the picture will be on a stack with the number of pictures.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this or guide me to a resource I could use to do it please? Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

yeah it is possible u need to create a whole separate frame for that and change it from user to user

Comment: Yes I know. But I don't know how to create the frame section so it looks like the Facebook one. Do you have any resource or anything that could help me? I tried searching online but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: u wont get ready mate easily well u can take example from my google+ collection xeon in that i hv used it so u can then ask me for the code u require for a specific frame

Comment: aryanbajaj27@gmail.com thats my id u can visit my page and see if u like something. i will definately help .

Comment: AryanBajaj00727 search it